# Do all Java output streams have buffers?

Tags: java, io

I used `OutputStreamWriter` with socket. When I tried to write data, I found that the data was not sent out. So I tried the `flush()` and it succeeded.

I would like to ask some question:

1. Do all output streams have a buffer ? So is there any unique benefit of a class like `BufferedOutputStream`? (Since there are buffers)
2. when I use `close()`. Has the data in the buffer disappeared or was flushed out? I tested it, the data in the buffer was not successfully written out. But I have seen in many places that calling the `close()` will flush the data in the buffer?

Comment: No. That's the reason why some classes have "Buffer" in their name, and others have not. And depending on context, when some framework creates a stream for you, and you only know "it is this or that basic interface" you actually don't know whether it is buffered or not.

Comment: Why do you think it was necessarily the OutputStream which contained the buffer in your case? OutputStreamWriter has its own buffer ["The resulting bytes are accumulated in a buffer"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html)

Comment: 2) The JavaDoc of `close` says "Closes the stream, **flushing it first**". Seems like most of your questions can be answered by just reading the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all `OutputStream` implementations have buffers.

That's trivially proven, since you can just implement your own.

But most uses of an `OutputStream` will often involve a buffer *at some level*.

`BufferedOutputStream` is the obvious candidate, where the buffer is diretly in the class as the primary feature of the class. This way you can add explicit buffering to any other `OutputStream`.

`OutputStream`s that communicate with the OS such as `FileOutputStream` or the `OutputStream` returned for a network connection don't have explicit buffers themselves, but will write to the OS which may or may not have its own buffer (for example most OS won't immediately write to a file on a `write` system call and only flush on close or after some time).

In either case (direct buffer in the `OutputStream` or an underlying system buffer) a `flush` call tends to initiate a write-back to the "real" target.

Note that a `flush` before a close should never be necessary on a conforming `OutputStream`.

Comment: @Michael: Do feel empowered to make edits like this.

Comment: thx !  I'm still a little bit confused. You said "a flush before a close should never be necessary on a conforming OutputStream."  Will calling close automatically flush? and i browsed the doc , it says that "Closes the stream, flushing it first". Is this also based on the specific implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Not all `OutputStream` implementations perform buffering, although buffering is quite a common feature that they had the `flush()` method defined as part of the contract of `OutputStream` (specifically by extending a `Flushable` interface). I think the best source of information about this is the [Javadoc of that method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#flush()):

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be written out. The general contract of flush is that calling it is an indication that, **if any bytes previously written have been buffered by the implementation of the output stream**, such bytes should immediately be written to their intended destination.
>
> If the intended destination of this stream is an abstraction provided by the underlying operating system, for example a file, then flushing the stream guarantees only that bytes previously written to the stream are passed to the operating system for writing; it does not guarantee that they are actually written to a physical device such as a disk drive.
>
> The `flush` method of `OutputStream` does nothing.

I've highlighted the part where it's clear that it depends on the implementation whether or not buffering is implemented.